# Array.push doesn't work for two dimentional array

Tags: ruby, arrays, push

I'm trying to add more elements to a two dimentional array in ruby but the .push method doesn't work. In the screenshot, I printed out all the elements and the final line is the array.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
def solution(a)
  x = 0
  y = 1
  coordinates = [[0, 0]]
  a.each_with_index do |i, index|
    next_coordinate = coordinates[coordinates.length-1]
    case (index%4)
    when 0
      next_coordinate[y] += i
    when 1
      next_coordinate[x] += i
    when 2
      next_coordinate[y] -= i
    else
      next_coordinate[x] -= i
    end
    puts next_coordinate.to_s
    coordinates.push(next_coordinate)
  end
  return coordinates.to_s
end

a = [1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 4, 6, 3, 2]
puts solution(a)
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: [[0, 0], [0, 1], [3, 1], [3, -1], [-2, -1], [-2, 3], [2, 3], [2, -3], [-1, -3], [-1, -1]]

Comment: Please consider adding your results to the question as text, not as a screen shot.  A screen shot can't be cut-and-pasted, and it's harder to read.  Your expected output should also go in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code using same array object multiple times.

The code is doing something like following:

```
a = [[1]]
a.push(a[-1])
a
# => [[1], [1]]
a[-1][0] += 1
a
# => [[2], [2]]
```

Simple workaround is copy the object using `clone` method.

```
next_coordinate = coordinates[coordinates.length-1].clone
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def solution(a)
  a.each_with_index.inject([[0, 0]]) do |c, (i,index)|
    c.push( c.last.clone.tap do |nc| 
        xy=1-index%2
        sign=(1-2*((index/2)%2)))
        nc[xy] += i * sign 
     end
    )
  end
end
```